# Python List Index Ouf Of Range In IF Statement

Tags: python, list, file, indexing

So i have multiple patients' information stored in database.txt and i want to retrieve the data from the file into a list.

And the system prompt for patient's id to search and display other information of the patient such as Name, Age, Group & Zone.

However, i'm getting error from line 12, but the similar syntax in line 17 is able to run without problem.

```
search_keyword = input() # Asks for patient's name or id  (either one)
with open("database.txt", "r") as database:
     for data in database:
         for patients in data.split('|'):
             patient_details = []
             for details in patients.split(','):
                 patient_details.append(details)
             print(patient_details) # test
             print(len(patient_details) # test
             print(patient_details.index('Patient001')) # test
             print(patient_details[4]) # test
             if search_keyword == patient_details[0] or search_keyword == patient_details[4]: # error occured here, where it says list index out of range.
                        print("Name: " + patient_details[0])
                        print("Age: " + patient_details[1])
                        print("Group: " + patient_details[2])
                        print("Zone: " + patient_details[3])
                        print("ID: " + patient_details[4]) # no error here, patient_details[4] is able to display patient's id
```

database.txt

```
John,18,A,1,Patient001|Nick,20,F,9,Patient002
```

Test command for line 8,9, 10 and 11:

```
Line 8: [John, 18, A, 1, Patient001]
Line 9: 5
Line 10: 4
Line 11: IndexError: list index out of range
```

Can someone explain why this is happening, and any solutions regarding this issue without using any imported modules? Thank you for any assistance.

Comment: Try printing `patient_details` before the `if` statement. You probably have a data point that is not what you expect.

Comment: Thank you for replying! I have tested it out by adding print(patient_details) before the IF statement, and the outcome would be [John,18,A,1,Patient001], which is a perfect list i'm looking for with index[4] as patient id. But i had to also make changes to the IF statement to search_keyword == patient_details[0], because patient_details[4] would throw an error.

Comment: I'm not sure why the list is perfect when printed out before IF statement, but it throws an index list out of range error when it is used to in next line of IF statement.

Answer (score 0):

Imo a very good use-case for a [**named tuple:**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple)

```
from collections import namedtuple

text = "John,18,A,1,Patient001|Nick,20,F,9,Patient002"

# build database
Patient = namedtuple('Patient', ['name', 'age', 'group', 'zone', 'id'])
db = [Patient(*patient) for entry in text.split("|") for patient in [entry.split(",")]]

# Asks for patient's id
search_keyword = input("Please give an ID: ") 

# query the database
result = [patient for patient in db if patient.id == search_keyword]
# or patient.id.startswith(), etc.

print(result)
```

---

Without any imported modules, you could use

```
text = "John,18,A,1,Patient001|Nick,20,F,9,Patient002"

# build database
db = [entry.split(",") for entry in text.split("|")]

search_keyword = input("Please give an ID: ") # Asks for patient's id

# query the database
result = [patient for patient in db if patient[4] == search_keyword]
print(result)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, i will give it a look! Sadly, i'm not allowed to import external modules for my beginner project.

Comment: @Wesley: It is just a convenience, you could entirely do it without the named tuple.

Answer (score 0):

I see no flaw in the code. Although, I can point out a few ways to optimise it :

```py
patient_details = dict()
with open("database.txt", "r") as database:
    for data in database:
        for patients in data.split('|'):
            patients = patients.split(',')
            patient_details[patients[4]] = patients[0:4]

search_keyword = input() # Asks for patient's id
if patient_details.get(search_keyword, None):
    patient_detail = patient_details[search_keyword]
    print("Name: " + patient_detail[0])
    print("Age: " + patient_detail[1])
    print("Group: " + patient_detail[2])
    print("Zone: " + patient_detail[3])
    print("ID: " + search_keyword)
```

Using map instead of a linear search would allow you to search optimally.